# WPF/Silverlight rendering blur effect in realtime

Tags: wpf, multithreading, silverlight, dispatcher, blur

In my WPF project I've done with clicking some UI element such stuff:

```
    void vb1_click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
        dt.Tick += new System.EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Start();
    }

    void dt_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            this.vb2_blur_eff.Radius = (double)i;
        }
    }
```

The main problem is: "I can't see the each step of blur-effect per second. The program is idling and when the process is complete it gives me the final step of bluring the UI element.

I don't want it, cause both program idling is looking ugly and I want actually see the rendered result at the each period.

Comment: That's not the way animations work in WPF. Check www.wpftutorial.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem that I see is that you are using a For loop to set your Blur Radius, so it sits there cranks it up to max then returns control to the dispatcher which then updates it. I would prefer to do it with a StoryBoard but you can do it using a Timer and have the Timer set the Radius on each tick, when it reaches maximum then stop. You can use the Timer's interval to control the speed of the diffusion. I am using a Class level variable called count.

```
void vb1_click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 20);
    dt.Tick += new System.EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    count = 0;
    dt.Start();
}

void dt_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer tmr = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
    this.vb2_blur_eff.Radius = (double)count;
    if (count == 20)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        tmr.Tick -= new System.EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    }

    count += 1;
}
```